# Proof about inequality : $\frac{1}{(1+a^2)}+\frac{1}{(1+b^2)}+\frac{1}{(1+c^2)}\ge\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is a problem of inequality,
$a$,$b$,$c$ are strictly positive numbers, and $a+b+c=3.$
Prove that
$$\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2}\ge\frac{3}{2}$$
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $a, b, c \geq 1/\sqrt 3$ then this inequality follows from the Jensen’s inequality for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Don’t know if this helps much

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+c^2}=3-(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2})$$

Thus, we just need to prove:

$$\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\leq\frac{3}{2},$$

since $1+a^2\geq2a,$

$$\frac{a^2}{1+a^2}+\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{c^2}{1+c^2}\leq\frac{a^2}{2a}+\frac{b^2}{2b}+\frac{c^2}{2c}=\frac{3}{2}$$